# Is there a way to have \show not behave like an error?

Tags: errors, primitives

Everybody loves the `\show` tex primitive.

Sadly it so happens that whenever I `\show` something the execution/compilation which I call using `pdftex -halt-on-error` also stops, which was quite supprising to me having not perceived `\show` primitive to be an error. Can somebody please tell me to stop `\show` behaving like an error? Why was it behaving like an error in the first place?

the output after a show was used like this

```
\def\a{A}
\show\a
```

is the following

```
>\a=macro:
->A.
l.2 \show \a

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Besides my testing, also [this answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258816/111884) tells about `\shows` *behavioral problems* it states

> TeX will prompt the user for interaction in the event of an error
>   ('error' includes `\show` or similar) (The user may of course alter the
>   run mode within TeX using the related primitives.)

This seems to motivate this question further, as if I understand right there is a way to alter the run mode within TeX. I think that would be the way to stop `\show` being an error, but how?

Comment: @egreg The backgrounding issue is indeed the same to both questions, yet I think that this question is more directly asking the question, that is the behavior of `\show` while the other question was asking a more specific case and that is why I didn't spot it. If I was to internet search the question I would most likely find this question first, after all i do not even use texmaker or an ide

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
\scrollmode\show\foo
```

Which will stop `\show` stopping the run in normal tex processing (apparently the `-halt-on-error` commandline forces `\show` to stop even in `\scrollmode`)
but you always have the option of not using that option...

bit simpler and more flexible if you do not want it to stop is to use

```
\typeout{\meaning\foo}
```

as then you can adjust the text to requiremtnts

```
\typeout{the meaning of \string\foo\space is \meaning\foo}
```

Comment: Am I rightly thinking that it would best be `\message{\meaning\foo}` or similar for plain tex?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace `\message` or `\wlog` or `\write16` or any other similar thing yes, or `\def\typeout{\write16}` or ...

Comment: Is it just with my version of `pdftex` or does `\scrollmode\show\foo` not yield the desired effect, i.e. still yields a fatal error?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace hmm I'll adjust answer `\scrollmode` stops `\show` stopping but apparently `-halt-on-error` trumps that and makes it stop again, but why do that (I don't think I've ever used that option in 30 years of tex use)

Comment: Being that most errors subsequent to the first error might be rather consequential `-halt-on-error` option helps me to abort early and reduces the output and furthermore I can catch the exit status in the `bash` shell and script automatic handling regarding the result of `pdftex`, it can be  `imho` a good , at least if you do not use a ide

Comment: @humanityANDpeace but the _default_ behaviour is to stop at the first error if you just used `pdftex` it would stop at the first error unless you use `\scrollmode` or `\batchmode` etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43998/discussion-between-humanityandpeace-and-david-carlisle).