# How can I make TeX stop on the first error, but do not stop on \show (or \tl_show:n)?

Tags: errors, expl3

I want TeX to terminate on any error, because I only care about the first error and so that it finishes faster.

Unfortunately, if I use either `-interaction=errorstopmode` (and run with `</dev/null`) or `-halt-on-error`,
any `\show` (or expl3's `\tl_show:n` command terminates the program.

Is there any way to stop TeX on first error, but don't stop on debug print commands?

Comment: Originally answered in chat.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59559893#59559893  I repost here for searchability

Comment: TeX reuses the error-handling routine for anything that halts the run, including `\show`: I think you are out-of-luck

Comment: Untested, but maybe `\message{\meaning\somecommand}` would work?

Comment: See also: [errors - Using \show in nonstopmode causes TeXmaker to raise false alarms. Any fix? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142630/using-show-in-nonstopmode-causes-texmaker-to-raise-false-alarms-any-fix?rq=1) and [primitives - Is there a way to have \show not behave like an error? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324911/is-there-a-way-to-have-show-not-behave-like-an-error?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach would be to turn locally to `\nonstopmode` and get back to `\errorstopmode` afterwards. With the manual overhead to always insert that before and after `\show` you're practically done and it works with every token:

```
\nonstopmode
\show{
\show}
\show\stop
\show\show
\errorstopmode
```

With the restriction to `N`-type arguments you could also automate this:

```
\newcommand\shownonstop[1]
  {%
    \nonstopmode
    \show#1%
    \errorstopmode
  }
```

If you don't want to accidentally change modes if you're not currently in `\errorstopmode` you could take a look at [how to get the current interaction mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355762/117050).

Both of the above would still result in a non-zero return value of TeX (so be considered a "failed" run).

Another possibility would be to reimplement the functionality yourself. A simple implementation would be

```
\newcommand\shownonstop[1]{\typeout{\string#1: \meaning#1}}
```

If you want to get the exact same formatting we have to invest a bit more work:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \shownonstop #1
  {
    \iow_term:x
      {
        >~
        \bool_lazy_or:nnTF
          { \token_if_cs_p:N #1 }
          { \token_if_macro_p:N #1 }
          {
            \token_to_str:N #1 =
            \token_if_primitive:NTF #1
              { \token_to_meaning:N #1 }
              { \exp_after:wN \my_shownonstop_macro:w \cs_meaning:N #1 \s_stop }
          }
          { \token_to_meaning:N #1 }
        .
      }
  }
\exp_last_unbraced:NNNNo
\cs_new:Npn \my_shownonstop_macro:w #1 \c_colon_str #2 \s_stop { #1: ^^J #2 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Remark: something like `\nonstopmode \expandafter \errorstopmode \show X` would not work because `\show` is [not expandable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467360/is-there-a-list-of-expandable-tex-primitives-latex-e-tex-others?noredirect=1&lq=1).