# LuaLaTeX does not handle control sequence consist of a single null character correctly?

Tags: luatex

I do the following:

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{pretty}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_analysis_show:n{o, x}
\let\prettyN\tl_analysis_show:n
\let\prettyO\tl_analysis_show:o
\let\prettyX\tl_analysis_show:x

%\let\prettyN\pretty:n
%\let\prettyO\pretty:o
%\let\prettyX\pretty:x
\ExplSyntaxOff

\catcode0=11\relax %letter
\prettyN{escape:\^^@}
\prettyX{detoken:\detokenize{\^^@}}
\prettyX{string:\string\^^@}
\prettyX{raw letter:^^@}

\end{document}
```

The output is roughly that LuaLaTeX seems to consider the escape sequence as an active character, the detokenize to be (backslash space), the\string to be (backslash). Raw letter remains correct.

PDFLaTeX's output appears to be as expected (control sequence, backslash null space)

Did I overlook something? Is this documented behavior or a bug?

Comment: Your MWE gives me an error with pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022).

Comment: @Thérèse Is it just what \tl_analysis_show:n does?

Comment: It chokes at `l.18 \prettyN{escape:\^^@}`

Comment: @Thérèse As I explained, \tl_analysis_show:n makes TeX pause. You can `-interaction=nonstopmode`, or [expl3 - How can I make TeX stop on the first error, but do not stop on \show (or \tl_show:n)? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621919/how-can-i-make-tex-stop-on-the-first-error-but-do-not-stop-on-show-or-tl-sho) (disclaimer: my question); although for a one-off repeatedly pressing return is an option.

Comment: So you’re comparing log files, not PDF output (there is none in either case)? I do see the difference in logs.

Comment: @Thérèse That's correct

Comment: I don't have `^^@` defined, so it comes up `undefined`. Instead, with `^^a`  (presumably = 97), output is OK (`\!`) and reported OK in all cases. What macro is `^^@` supposed to represent?

Comment: `\string\^^@` produces different output between Knuth TeX and LuaTeX. I've reported this inconsistency upstream: https://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2022-April/007678.html

Comment: @user202729 This should now be fixed upstream: https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/commit/3b9e88915e2b7fd33957ca50b294e234650bf540